# React-native converting synchronous GET api call to asynchronous GET

Tags: asynchronous, react-native, fetch, synchronous

I'm trying to make a synhronous api call in my code and react-native doesn't allow that. I tried using fetch asynchronously but I get a 'network request failed' error. Here is the code I'm trying to convert:

```
     var adfsUrl = null;
     var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     req.open('GET', url + '/XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0', true);
     req.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'Keep-Alive');
     req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8');
     req.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (req.readyState === 4) {
            if (req.status === 200) {
                adfsUrl = $(req.response).find('ms-xrm\\:Identifier');
            }
         }
     };
     return $(adfsUrl[0]).text().replace("http://", "https://");
```

My failed attempt code:

```
var adfsUrl = null;
try {
let response = await fetch(url + '/XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0',
{
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8',
    },
});
let responseJson = await response.json();
    adfsUrl = $(responseJson).find('ms-xrm\\:Identifier');
    return $(adfsUrl[0]).text().replace("http://", "https://");
} catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: your `await` won't work without `async`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I added async in the function declaration